# update database where there are more than 1 maximum values

Tags: php, mysql

i have a following table in database

```
B  | name
---|------
 3 | 
 3 | 
 1 |
```

by using this code

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET name='YES' WHERE B>0 ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 1";
```

the result is this

```
B  | name
---|------
 3 | YES
 3 | 
 1 |
```

but there are more than 1 highest value and i want to put YES on name where B has the highest value. the results should be like this.

```
B  | name
---|------
 3 | YES
 3 | YES
 1 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE products SET name = 'YES'
WHERE b IN (SELECT b FROM (SELECT MAX(B) b FROM products WHERE b > 0) x)
```

Note that there are 2 nested queries.

It is an **essential** trick to fool mysql since otherwise there will be an error that you're modifying the same table you're reading from.

General explanation:

1. Nested query selects the maximum value for the given column (in this case it's `3`)
2. Outer query (`UPDATE`) updates all the rows that satisfy the `b IN (3)` condition

Comment: It is possible, it is even an example statement in the manual. It has only minor restrictions what the current value of a column is. But a set on one column based on a where on the other is fine. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html -

Comment: @eckes I cannot see your point. Could you please clarify? Please check your link once again, especially this line: "Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."

Comment: it works, but im a beginner. care to explain? hehe thanks :)

Comment: @Smurf added something

Comment: I am refering to "If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression, UPDATE uses the current value of the column." and related examples.

Comment: @eckes that's not the case here. Please check the question and my answer once again. There is a conceptual difference between addressing the values in the **current row** and in the **whole table** using a **nested query**. If you still don't get it - please spend some time and try to answer the question yourself and run your query on a real database.

Comment: @zerkms no idea what you mean but I guess it doesnt matter anyway. You need a subselect for the query because mysql cannot mix group queries with normal ones, its not related to the update (as the manual shows there are sample staetemens which do update itself).

Comment: @eckes: "as the manual shows there are sample staetemens which do update itself" --- you normally cannot do that (unless you put it into double nested query). And you would know that if you read the manual more carefully and try that instead of arguing. And thank you for the downvote, it's funny when someone who cannot understand the problem downvotes. It's also surprising that a Chief Architect is not smart enough to make a research before they argue about things they have no idea about. Have fun though.

Comment: @eckes anyway, would you be so kind to demonstrate your "It is possible" query? It is not hard for you is it? :-D

Comment: sure, as I said the example is in the manual and it works: http://pastebin.com/dEMMi1EQ

Comment: @eckes you don't have a nested query here. Try to solve asked question without 2 nested queries

Comment: exactly: i can update a table without using a nested query. You said you need a nested query to do it. and i said you dont need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69354/discussion-between-zerkms-and-eckes).

Comment: @eckes "You said you need a nested query to do it" --- unless I did not say *that*.

Comment: Nah thanks I guess its clear that the "You cannot modify a table you read from" can be interpreted differently. You could put a "with a subselect" in it to make it unabiqous.

Comment: @eckes: well, the answer was given for a particular question. And the comments have been left for a particular query. Literally any phrase may be treated by someone as ambiguous, just because they don't have anything better to do but to annoy others. And there is an explicit note that I'm speaking about nested queries. Just one line above what you've quoted. You see - the phrase is ambiguous only if you read not the whole text, but a part of it (which is weird you know). If someone is not patient enough to read 3 lines of text carefully - no reason to explain further.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE products
   SET name = 'YES'
 WHERE B = (SELECT MAX(B) FROM products WHERE B > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query before that selecting the max value of the rows, so it would be 3. Then just update the rows with the value 3 putting YES on them.